# Data string to string array conversion in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsoup

I have a string; I want to convert into a string array. How do I do it? Is there any java built in function? I'm using jsoup.
The response data have the form:

```
[null, [
    ["s9747187", "Менеуз-Москва", "авт.ост. Менеуз-Москва, Республика Башкортостан"],
    ["c213", "Москва", "г. Москва, Москва и Московская область, Россия"],
    ["s2000008", "Москва (Рижский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Рижский вокзал), Москва"],
    ["s9746351", "Москва, автостанция Новоясеневская", "авт.вкз. Москва, автостанция Новоясеневская, Москва"],
    ["s2000005", "Москва (Павелецкий вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Павелецкий вокзал), Москва"],
    ["s9637033", "Москва, автостанция Тёплый Стан", "авт.вкз. Москва, автостанция Тёплый Стан, Москва"],
    ["s9845745", "Москва, Южные ворота", "авт.вкз. Москва, Южные ворота, Москва"],
    ["s2000002", "Москва (Ярославский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Ярославский вокзал), Москва"],
    ["s2000006", "Москва (Белорусский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Белорусский вокзал), Москва"],
    ["s2000009", "Москва (Савёловский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Савёловский вокзал), Москва"]
]]
```

Comment: Yes you can do that, I am quite sure about it. Do a bit of research and you will find a good solution for your problem.

Comment: I did a research. I read that there are two types of data: xml, json. These data do not have this type.

Comment: That's not exactly what you would call research now. Or to phrase it better: It is not an amount of research that validates asking here for others to do the remaining research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this;
keep data into string:

```
String jsonData = "[null, [
["s9747187", "Менеуз-Москва", "авт.ост. Менеуз-Москва, Республика Башкортостан"],
["c213", "Москва", "г. Москва, Москва и Московская область, Россия"],
["s2000008", "Москва (Рижский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Рижский вокзал), Москва"],
["s9746351", "Москва, автостанция Новоясеневская", "авт.вкз. Москва, автостанция Новоясеневская, Москва"],
["s2000005", "Москва (Павелецкий вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Павелецкий вокзал), Москва"],
["s9637033", "Москва, автостанция Тёплый Стан", "авт.вкз. Москва, автостанция Тёплый Стан, Москва"],
["s9845745", "Москва, Южные ворота", "авт.вкз. Москва, Южные ворота, Москва"],
["s2000002", "Москва (Ярославский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Ярославский вокзал), Москва"],
["s2000006", "Москва (Белорусский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Белорусский вокзал), Москва"],
["s2000009", "Москва (Савёловский вокзал)", "вкз. Москва (Савёловский вокзал), Москва"]
]]";
```

then parse using this method, it will return string array-

```
public  ArrayList<String>getData(String jsonData)
{
    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONArray newJson= jsonArray.getJSONArray(1);


        for (int i = 0; i < newJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray newJsonArray = newJson.getJSONArray(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < newJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                     String data = newJsonArray.getString(j);
                      stringArray.add(data);
            }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  stringArray;
}
```

Comment: how i use gson?

Comment: what do you want to use. my example is showing to parsing data and set into string array. You can also use gson for parsing this.

Comment: if you want to use gson for parsing then tell me i will update my ans with gson parsing